# How to test the amazon alexa custom skill through your alexa enabled device while in development phase?

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I have created a skill and would like to test it on the device itself?

I have managed to test it on echosim.io.

Answer (score 14):

On the test step at developer.amazon.com I can enable it for testing: `This skill is enabled for testing on your account`

I guess you have to use the same amazon account in the alexa app and in the developer console.

> You will be able to see your skill in the Skills tab in Alexa App and
>   you can enable the skill and start testing.
>
> [...]
>
> The skill is available in "Skills > Your Skills" page of the Alexa App
>   when you select 'Yes' above. You can then enable the skill and test
>   its functionality by asking Alexa, ...

Comment: this is best answer available

Answer (score 2):

We have created a tool just for this case:
https://bespoken.tools/blog/2016/08/24/introducing-bst-proxy-for-alexa-skill-development

Here is a brief visual depiction of how it works:
[image]
The bst proxy sends requests directly from Alexa to your local development environment. So you can use your Echo device to interact directly with your in-development Alexa skill.